# NVML supported on Jetson TK1?

Tags: cuda, nvml

I installed NVML on Jetson TK1 and compiled a cuda program. The compilation does not show any error but when running it shows the error

> /NVML-installed-path/usr/src/gdk/nvml/lib//libnvidia-ml.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized.

The downloaded NVML library is for Linux 64 bit. Does Jetson TK1 supports NVML library?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run `nvidia-smi` on that Jetson?  I'm not surprised that a 64-bit linux library doesn't work on Jetson.  Jetson is not a 64-bit CPU platform.

Comment: When I run nvidia-smi, it shows `-bash: nvidia-smi: command not found`. Then I installed 32 bit version of NVML. When I compile the program `nvcc Prog1.cu -o Prog1 -L/Installed-Path/usr/src/gdk/nvml/lib/ -I/Installed-Path/usr/include/nvidia/gdk/ -arch sm_30 -lnvidia-ml`, it shows `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /Installed-Path/usr/src/gdk/nvml/lib//` `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvidia-ml`

Comment: Yes, I don't believe NVML (and therefore nvidia-smi) is currently supported on Jetson.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [NVML API reference](http://ocs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/index.html) there is no support for Tegra devices. Jetson TK1 comes with a Tegra K1 SOC processor.

If that is not the reason why it doesn't work I only can think of one possibility: [Tegra K1 SOC has a Kepler](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1) inside and NVML library came out for CUDA 4, which if I don't missunderstood is a later release of the Nvidia computing toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

NVML and nvidia-smi are currently (April 2020) not supported on the Jetson platform. For more information, see the [JetPack documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/jetpack/index.html).

you can install jetson-stats to monitor GPU, CPU, Mem, swap, Disk usage, Power, clocks, etc

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U jetson-stats
```

you may need to update pip. for that use -

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after installation -

```
sudo jtop
```